# How do I retrieve SQL information from a dropdown menu in OOP PHP

Tags: php, sql, oop, drop-down-menu

So I have a database table containing many customers infos. I want to do a CRUD where when a customer is selected on a dropdown menu, it shows in the input fields of my HTML so I can update and delete it. Do I have to use javascript for this? I have one index, one database class and one Customer class.

My index:

```
<?php
include_once("Customer.class.php");
include_once("DB_manager.class.php");
$db = new DB_manager();
$db->getAllCustomersName();

if(isset($_POST["button3"])){

    if(isset($_POST["chkbox"])){
        $newmember = "Yes";
    }else{
        $newmember = "No";
    }

    $info = array(
        "customerNumber"=>$_POST["CustNumber"],
        "customerName"=>$_POST["Middlename"],
        "contactLastName"=>$_POST["Lastname"],
        "contactFirstName"=>$_POST["Firstname"],
        "phone"=>$_POST["phone"],
        "addressLine1"=>$_POST["add1"],
        "addressLine2"=>$_POST["add2"],
        "city"=>$_POST["city"],
        "state"=>$_POST["state"],
        "postalCode"=>$_POST["pc"],
        "country"=>$_POST["country"],
        "salesRepEmployeeNumber"=>$_POST["salesR"],
        "creditLimit"=>$_POST["limit"],
        "membership"=>$_POST["rdiobox"],
        "newClient"=>$newmember
        );

    $customer = new Customer($info);
    $db->addCustomer($customer);
}

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Customer DB</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<header class="fix">
<h1>Herzing College<span>Manipulate Customer Database</span></h1>
</header>
<form>
    <div><label for="clients" class="fs">Select Customer:</label>
        <select name="clients" id="clients" class="fw" onchange="changeCustomer()">
            <?php foreach ($_SESSION["data"] as $value) { ?>
            <option><?php echo $value["customerNumber"] . " - " . $value["contactFirstName"] . " " . $value["contactLastName"] . " - " . $value["customerName"];} ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<form id="ws" method="post" action="#">

<div class="divform">
    <div class="r">
        <div class="c"><label for="CustNumber" class="fs">Customer Number:</label><input id="CustNumber" name="CustNumber" type="text" required="true" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="Middlename" class="fs">Customer Name:</label><input id="Middlename" name="Middlename" type="text" required="true" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="Firstname" class="fs">Contact First Name:</label><input id="Firstname" name="Firstname" type="text" required="true" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="Lastname" class="fs">Contact Last Name:</label><input id="Lastname" name="Lastname" type="text" required="true" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="phone" class="fs">Phone:</label><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" / required="true" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div><label for="add1" class="fs">Address 1:</label><input id="add1" name="add1" type="text" class="fw" required="true"/></div>
<div><label for="add2" class="fs">Address 2:</label><input id="add2" name="add2" type="text" class="fw"/></div>
<div class="divform">
    <div class="r">
        <div class="c"><label for="city" class="fs" required="true">City:</label><input id="city" name="city" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="state" class="fs">State:</label><input id="state" name="state" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="pc" class="fs" required="true">Postal Code:</label><input id="pc" name="pc" type="text" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="country" class="fs" required="true">Country:</label><input id="country" name="country" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="r">
        <div class="c"><span class="fheading fs">Membership</span><input id="rdiobox" name="rdiobox" type="radio" value="Premium" required="true" /><label for="rdiobox">Premium</label> <input id="rdiobox2" name="rdiobox" type="radio" value="Free" required="true" /><label for="rdiobox2">Free</label></div>
        <div class="c"><span class="fheading fs">New Member</span><input id="chkbox" name="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="Yes"><label for="chkbox">Yes / No</label></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="limit" class="fs">Credit Limit:</label><input id="limit" name="limit" type="text" required="true" /></div>
        <div class="c"><label for="salesR" class="fs" >Sales Representative #:</label><input id="salesR" name="salesR" type="text" required="true" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="r">
        <div class="c"><input name="button1" type="submit" value="Edit" /></div>
        <div class="c"><input name="button2" type="submit" value="Delete" /></div>
        <div class="c"><input name="button3" type="submit" value="Add New Client" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>

</div>        
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var select = document.getElementById("clients");

function changeCustomer(){
    selectedCustomer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My database class:

```
<?php 

/**
/**
    This is my Database manager class for the customers CRUD.
    @author Francis Charpentier
    @copyright 2014 Herzing Colllege
    @version 1.0
**/
/**
    *Constructor
    *@param none
    *@return void
**/
class DB_manager{
    private $_theDB;

    public function __construct(){
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbUser = "root";
        $dbPass = "";
        $dbName = "herzing";

        try{
            $this->_theDB = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbHost.";dbname=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
            $this->_theDB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        } catch(Exception $e){
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function addCustomer($obj){
        $query = $this->_theDB->prepare("INSERT INTO customers (customerNumber, customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country, salesRepEmployeeNumber, creditLimit, membership, newClient) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        $insertedID = 0;

        try{
            $this->_theDB->beginTransaction();
            $query->execute(array(
                $obj->getCustomerNumber(),
                $obj->getCustomerName(),
                $obj->getContactLastName(),
                $obj->getContactFirstName(),
                $obj->getPhone(),
                $obj->getAddressLine1(),
                $obj->getAddressLine2(),
                $obj->getCity(),
                $obj->getState(),
                $obj->getPostalCode(),
                $obj->getCountry(),
                $obj->getSalesRepEmployeeNumber(),
                $obj->getCreditLimit(),
                $obj->getMembership(),
                $obj->getNewClient()
            ));

            $insertedID = $this->_theDB->lastInsertId();
            $this->_theDB->commit();
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->_theDB->rollback();
        }

        return $insertedID;
    }

    public function getAllCustomersName(){
        $query = $this->_theDB->query("SELECT * FROM customers");
        $_SESSION["data"] = $query->fetchAll();

        return $_SESSION["data"];
    }

}
 ?>
```

The Customer class only contains a basic constructor and getters and setters.
Adding a customer works perfectly, I just can't get the info from the select input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no. you don't "have" to use JS for anything. it just makes things more convenient/quicker.

Comment: You'll see that a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845082/fetching-values-to-textbox-from-database-based-on-drop-down-selection) was considered "too broad". You should probably attempt to take this a bit further on your own and come back with a specific problem/issue/error.